# Ubuntu Budgie 17.04: apt does not work, at all

Tags: apt, updates, aptitude, 17.04, budgie

This is a fresh 17.04 install, but I am reusing a `/home` setup from past Debian derivative installations.

Every package that I have tried to install so far fails with an error that looks something like this:

```
missingfaktor@going-merry:~$ sudo apt-get install ghc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ghc : Depends: gcc but it is not installable
       Depends: libgmp-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libffi-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libbsd-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libncurses5-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried the usual suspects - `autoremove`, `update`, and `upgrade`. But that did not help.

```
missingfaktor@going-merry:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

missingfaktor@going-merry:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                        
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease [243 kB]                                                               
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease                                                
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
Fetched 243 kB in 0s (407 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

missingfaktor@going-merry:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Could you please help me resolve the issue with my `apt`?

This is what my `sources.list` looks like for reference:

```
missingfaktor@going-merry:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Budgie 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any `main` repository enabled

Comment: @steeldrive, you are right. That was it. Thanks! If you could post this as an answer, I could select it.